# Read Loop Over String in Racket Scheme

Tags: parsing, scheme, iteration, racket

I'm using Racket Scheme. I have a string defined and I'm attempting to parse it.

I initially have

```
(define expression (open-input-string "(expression here)"))
```

And now I'm attempting to iterate over all the characters using the scheme read function. I'm new to scheme though and I'm not quite sure how to properly loop them.

Essentially I need to loop all

```
read-char expression
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want plain `read` for something like this. It is built to read Scheme/Racket syntax, not arbitrary data. Instead, you probably want [`string->list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string-%3Elist#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-~3elist%29%29), which splits a string into a list of characters.

```
(string->list "(expression here)")
; => '(#\( #\e #\x #\p #\r #\e #\s #\s #\i #\o #\n #\space #\h #\e #\r #\e #\))
```

Perhaps you don't want to read the whole string at once, though? There does exist a [`read-char`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html?q=read-char#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-char%29%29) function, as you include in your post. There are lots of ways to loop in Racket. You can use recursion, or you can use Racket's [plethora of `for` loop forms](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html).

Still, if you have an input port and you just want to loop over all the characters, well, there's an easy way to do that, too! You can use the handy [`in-input-port-chars`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-chars#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-input-port-chars%29%29) sequence with `for` loops like this:

```
(define expression (open-input-string "(expression here)"))
(for ([c (in-input-port-chars expression)])
  (display c))
; => (expression here)
```

Comment: My strings are actually going to be in scheme syntax format, ex: `(- 4 (+ 3 5))` And I will be parsing the data from it, Is this still the best method? I was thinking just read may suffice, this helped me with the for loop though, thank you.

Comment: @BelginFish It would help if you added some examples of what you actually wanted to parse to your question.

Comment: It's ok, the second example code you provided was all I needed. Thank you.